# A suggestion to manage "big" HTML select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, select

I did a simple web application using AJAX and jQuery. I have a form with a series of items inserted in a select that are filtered on customer's name. I update the select datas with jQuery when the customer change. 
My problem is that because items are a lot, around 20.000 for each customer, when I do the update often appears a javascript alert message that the jquery-library script can be busy or has ended to work.
So I'm looking for some suggestion to manage these big data.

EDIT Some code if it can be useful

```js
function cstm_itm(id_for, id_art, tip){

    fade( $('#'+id_art) , 0 ,function(){});

 var dati= 'for='+$('#'+id_for).val()+'&tip='+tip;

    $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: 'cstm_itm_upd.php',
            data: dati, 
            beforeSend: function (http) {
                http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                },
            success: function(response){

                    fade( $('#'+id_art), 0, 
      function(){
        $('#'+id_art).html(response);
       $('#'+id_art).change();
       fade( $('#'+id_art) , 1 , 
        function(){}
        );
       }
      );
                }
    });
}
```

```html
<select id="n_art_d_s" class="field" tabindex="-1"
 onchange=" $('#n_art_d').val( $('#n_art_d_s').children(':selected').text() );
               $('#n_art_d_t').val( $('#n_art_d_s').children(':selected').text() );
               $('#n_art').val( this.value );
               $('#n_art_c_d_s').val($('#n_art_d_s').val());
               if($('#tmp_sta').val()==0) $('#n_art_c_d_s').change();
             " 
 onfocus=" $('#tmp_sta').val(0);" 

 style="width:25px; margin-left: .3em;  background-color: #edf7ff; " >
<option value="" selected=""></option>
<option value="123" title="Desc 1">Item 1</option>
<option value="456" title="Desc 2">Item 2</option>
...
</select>
```

EDIT-CLOSE I followed the suggestion of @2182349 and found [these](http://www.pontikis.net/blog/jquery-ui-autocomplete-step-by-step) example on which build my solution.

Comment: How would a select element containing 20,000 options be useful or usable by anyone?

Comment: Agreeing with @1252748 -- If you need to show 20,000 options simultaneously, perhaps a simple select element is not the UI you need.  Or perhaps you should investigate ways to break up those options, or only show a subset in any given select.  It seems like too much.

Comment: The best solution is establish a limit on how many items can be load without performance issue. If there are more records above limit use some kind of navigation to get next chunk of data.

Comment: clarify what you meant by "update the select datas" if you are setting the selected option, cost should be low. If you are updating the html inside of select tag (eg $select.html(newHtml) ), the cost should be low too. I do not see what is making things slow for you

Comment: Use an autocomplete to allow the users to select items. https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: @1252748 I agree: I suppose that there is something wrong in the anagrph logic of the customer but that is.

Comment: @anied My need is to give the possibility to select from a list of possible items, and all 20.000 have to be disponible. I can think to reduce the number after a partial typing reloading the elements on a filter (dbase query) but I'm not sure to follow these way.

Comment: @MaxZoom These require do develop a dedicated "select-like" element with doubt similar to my response to anied.

Comment: @Ji_in_coding I have initially all the items (30.000+), when I select the customer I have to query for extract only the customer's items and rebuild the options list. When these happen the jQuery library is called.

Comment: @user2182349 I will try, but I have to update the js array when the customer change.

Comment: @mYmage by logic: can you group all the 20k items by a similar attribute. Example: all the products available=20k. Then you split them by type: laptop, printers, monitors, mobile phone ecc. And this is the second select. Then you split by manufacturer. And you have the third select. Then you choose the items. It is impossible to find anything in a 20k long select!!

Comment: @LelioFaieta The problem is that the customers haven't a good item-code structure as I replayed to 1252748: one is '98456', other 'A55_3', other 'qaz_pt'.

Comment: Using jQuery and doing JavaScript with inline event handlers???

Comment: @epascarello be patient, I'm a begginer. Give me a suggestion where to learn to do things better. Thanks in advance.